# Add additional row and computed data in datagrid

Tags: c#

Currently this code creates and populates a row for each vertex.  How would I go about adding another row under each row already created with say...the value of (position.x ++ position y)in appropriate columns?  Simply adding empty row's is an easy thing to do.  Populating it is another task.

```
foreach (AcDb.ObjectId vertexId in poly)
    {
     if (!vertexId.ObjectClass.IsDerivedFrom(vertexClass))
         continue;

         var vertex = (AcDb.PolylineVertex3d)trans.GetObject(vertexId, AcDb.OpenMode.ForWrite);
                    System.Data.DataRow dr = vertexTable.NewRow();
                    dr.ItemArray = new object[] { vertex.Handle.Value, vertex.Position.X, vertex.Position.Y, vertex.Position.Z } ;
                    vertexTable.Rows.Add(dr);
```